# Ios+Redlaser + Product information

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I have been registered with redlaser with licence version, i have successfully used the sample app but not able to get the product information from the upc code, so how can i make it, is Redlaser providing the feature to get product information?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Redlaser iOS SDK provides only barcode scanning functionality. There is no out of the box feature from Redlaser to get product information.